# sprintf() in c++ with conditional statements

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I'm trying to format a char array with sprintf() for an arduino project in C++
My goal is to format the following integers: day,month,year,hour,minute and second into the following

DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS

My issue arises when an integer is < 10 I loose the format which I try and correct with the following sprintf

```
 sprintf (timeStr, "%c%u/%c%u/%u %c%u:%c%u:%c%u",(monthDay>0 && monthDay<=9)?'0':'',monthDay,(month>0 && month<=9)?'0':'',month,year,(hour>0 && hour<=9)?'0':'',hour,(minute>0 && minute<=9)?'0':'',minute,(second>0 && second<=9)?'0':'',second);
```

Now this wont compile because i get "empty character constant" which I assume comes from the '' not having a legal value.

I'm stuck on how I can use sprintf to format a string if the %c in the statement is conditional and I only want a value if its <10

If anyone has any insight into how I could achieve this I would highly appreciate it as I'm really stuck on it!

Thank you!

Comment: lookup the printf formats and use something like "%02d" to specify a width of 2 left padded with 0s.

Comment: if sprintf can't work, why not to use strcat instead, since you don't want to output when value is < 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're correct that `%c` requires a character (which an empty `''` is *not,* by the way).

But, if you're after zero-padding, just use the format specifier `"%02d"`? That's how you normally get zero-padded numbers. In other words, use:

```
sprintf (timeStr, "%02d/%02d/%04d %02d:%02d:%02d",
    monthDay, month, year, hour, minute, second);
```

Many embedded systems may exclude floating point specifiers (or may make them optional) in order to preserve space but zero-padding or space-padding integers is a fairly simple operation that they all should have.

If you find an implementation so deficient that it *doesn't* support them, you can use strings instead of characters, since the empty string *is* valid:

```
sprintf (timeStr, "%s%d/%s%d/%d %s%d:%s%d:%s%d",
    (monthDay < 10) ? "0" : "",
    monthDay,
    :
    and so on ...
```

But I'm pretty certain Arduino isn't *that* deficient.

Comment: Ah! thanks, I was under the impression that they only existed for the base types as %d, %c, %lf etc, from the lists I had researched didn't realize it expands from that.

I was heading in the wrong direction, thanks again for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

The %c format always requires exactly one character, so `''` isn't allowed. You want to print something that's either zero or one character. You can use %s for that, and make the conditional expression use string literals instead of character literals: `(monthDay > 0 && monthDay <= 9) ? "0" : ""`.

Comment: **Edit: I misread it was using %s instead of %c and understand your solution now**


I had tried this solution prior to the post, instead you get a compiler error that it expects a char not char array, I tried to be smart and do this:

`char *c = "";
(monthDay > 0 && monthDay <= 9) ? "0" : c[0]`

which compiles although actually references the '/0' null terminator of the char array